# How to convert aggregates in pandas into string?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I have a pandas dataframe which contains date and some values something like below

Original data:

```
list = [('2018-10-29', 6.1925), ('2018-10-29', 6.195), ('2018-10-29', 1.95833333333333), ('2018-10-29', 1.785), ('2018-10-29', 3.05), ('2018-10-29', 1.30666666666667), ('2018-10-29', 1.6325), ('2018-10-30', 1.765), ('2018-10-30', 1.265), ('2018-10-30', 2.1125), ('2018-10-30', 2.16714285714286), ('2018-10-30', 1.485), ('2018-10-30', 1.72), ('2018-10-30', 2.754), ('2018-10-30', 1.79666666666667), ('2018-10-30', 1.27833333333333), ('2018-10-30', 3.48), ('2018-10-30', 6.19), ('2018-10-30', 6.235), ('2018-10-30', 6.11857142857143), ('2018-10-30', 6.088), ('2018-10-30', 4.3), ('2018-10-30', 7.80666666666667), ('2018-10-30', 7.78333333333333), ('2018-10-30', 10.9766666666667), ('2018-10-30', 2.19), ('2018-10-30', 1.88)]
```

After loading into pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list)


             0          1
0   2018-10-29   6.192500
1   2018-10-29   6.195000
2   2018-10-29   1.958333
3   2018-10-29   1.785000
4   2018-10-29   3.050000
5   2018-10-29   1.306667
6   2018-10-29   1.632500
7   2018-10-30   1.765000
8   2018-10-30   1.265000
9   2018-10-30   2.112500
10  2018-10-30   2.167143
11  2018-10-30   1.485000
12  2018-10-30   1.720000
13  2018-10-30   2.754000
14  2018-10-30   1.796667
15  2018-10-30   1.278333
16  2018-10-30   3.480000
17  2018-10-30   6.190000
18  2018-10-30   6.235000
19  2018-10-30   6.118571
20  2018-10-30   6.088000
21  2018-10-30   4.300000
22  2018-10-30   7.806667
23  2018-10-30   7.783333
24  2018-10-30  10.976667
25  2018-10-30   2.190000
26  2018-10-30   1.880000
```

I can easily find out certain statistic results like mean, variance, median etc. This is what I do

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list)
df.set_index(0, inplace=True)

variance = df.var()
print(variance)
```

I get the result below

```
1    6.918711
dtype: float64
```

Similarly,

```
print(df.mean())
```

I get the result below

```
1    3.759699
dtype: float64
```

Now I want to append these results to a list with a description for each of them

So if I do a string concatenation to the output for example

```
print("variance " + df.var().to_string())
```

I get the result as

```
variance 1    6.918711
```

If I try to append it to a list

```
lis = []
lis.append("variance " + df.var().to_string())
print(lis)
```

I get the list as

```
['variance 1    6.918711']
```

I see it is showing `1` as the column name but I want just the metric not the column number too

So it should be `variance 6.918711` and the list should look like

```
 ['variance 6.918711', 'mean 3.759699']
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
In [458]: variance = df.var().iloc[0]

In [459]: variance
Out[459]: 6.918710915931824

In [460]: mean = df.mean().iloc[0]

In [461]: mean
Out[461]: 3.7596992945326284
```

Now,column name is removed.

```
In [466]: lis = []
In [468]: lis.append('variance ' +str(variance))

In [469]: lis.append('mean ' +str(mean))

In [470]: lis
Out[470]: ['variance 6.918710915931824', 'mean 3.7596992945326284']
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the values which you want to keep from describe after that you can convert to string and add.

```
values = ['count','mean']
df.describe().loc[values].reset_index().astype(str).apply('   '.join,1).tolist()
```

Out:

```
['count   27.0', 'mean   3.7596992945326284']
```